# Exception for path of "/null" being thrown on all controller index methods

Tags: c#, exception, iis, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

As of today all branches of our codebase (old and new), our staging environment and our live environment are all throwing the following exception when the Index method of any Controller is viewed in a browser:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/null' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

To clarify, this is even happening on code that has long since been checked in and has not been edited, when I open the project and browse to the homepage of the application. Other members of the team are also experiencing this on their own branches as of this morning too.

The exception is thrown but the respective Index page is rendered as you'd expect so the exception being thrown is silent to the user.

It looks to have started happening on our production site at just after midnight. No publish was undertaken and no Windows Updates were installed on the server. I did install yesterday's wave of Windows Updates on my own PC. I'm baffled! Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your routes and application startup code. It sounds like there might be an Easter egg in your code somewhere.

Comment: I would agree if it weren't for the fact that it happened on the same morning for all branches of code being worked upon by each developer and also happens on a 6 week old, untouched branch.

Comment: Having investigated our logs, this looks to have happened on Friday 13th only. I wish I was joking but I'm not! Nothing was published, yet all environments have stopped throwing the exception. I do not like this!